# ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to reproduce the following tutorial https://csl.name/post/c-functions-python/.

My Python extension in **C++** looks like:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* py_myFunction(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
  char *s = "Hello from C!";
  return Py_BuildValue("s", s);
}

static PyObject* py_myOtherFunction(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
  double x, y;
  PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "dd", &x, &y);
  return Py_BuildValue("d", x*y);
}

static PyMethodDef extPy_methods[] = {
  {"myFunction", py_myFunction, METH_VARARGS},
  {"myOtherFunction", py_myOtherFunction, METH_VARARGS},
  {NULL, NULL}
};

void initextPy(void)
{
  (void) Py_InitModule("extPy", extPy_methods);
}
```

I am using the following **setup.py**:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='extPy', version='1.0',  \
ext_modules=[Extension('extPy', ['extPy.cpp'])])
```

After invoking it with `python setup.py install` the .so file seems to be in the right place.

But when I try to use this extension with `import extPy` I get the Error:

*ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function*

What am I missing here? Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the function `initextPy` is a C++ function which causes the C++ compiler to [*mangle* the name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) so it's not recognizable.

You need to mark the function as `extern "C"` to inhibit the name mangling:

```
extern "C" void initextPy(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This did the job. Thank you.